# Migration flags should be more general than “questions about video games”

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, video-games, migration

Recently, I tried to flag https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31792/how-does-one-keep-up-a-poker-face as “Definitely off topic: Probably Board-Gaming related (maybe not even that)”. Unfortunately, when flagging as off-topic, the only options are

- Questions about video games are off-topic here, but can be asked on Arqade.
- Questions about the development of video games are off-topic here, but can be asked on the Game Development Stack Exchange.
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

  - It belongs on meta.rpg.stackexchange.com – discussion, support, and feature requests for this site

There is no generic “Definitely off-topic, but I don't know where it would belong” option, and it would also be nice to add options for the three other Stack Exchange sites I have often seen migration suggestions to, so I would expand this list by:

- Questions about fictional settings are generally off-topic here (unless the setting is nearly exclusively a role playing setting) and should be asked on [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com)
- Questions concerning historical settings should be asked on [History Stack Exchange](http://history.stackexchange.com)
- Questions about board and card games are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com).

(This question is very similar to https://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/migration-flags-should-be-more-general-than-questions-about-computer-based-game, I stole the title from there, but since that one is marked as `status-completed`, Thunderforge suggested asking this as a new question.)

Comment: Regarding History and Boardgames and migration targets - I was under the impression that sites in beta aren't considered to be good migration targets, since they might not make it past beta. It's a bit frustrating when sometimes they're *exactly* the right site, but what can you do.

Comment: In that case, there should be a generic “This question is off-topic here, but might be welcome on on another site in the Stack Exchange network (including beta sites)” option or something like that. (Also, what speaks against giving beta sites the attention they deserve, but that's not for this discussion.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

doppelgreener covers the general stuff well, but doesn't mention why there are such a dearth of migration options for flag-privilege users.

Basically, StackExchange hates question migration.

There's good reason for the hate. Often, questions are off topic because they're about the wrong subject, but they're *also* off topic on the target site. In the past these have been migrated, closed by the target site, and then the target site's users have more-or-less politely told the migrating site's users not dump their garbage on them.

Since migration flags were almost always wrong and justified migrations were so rare, they're now the exclusive province of the mods, and removing the almost-never-useful flag options improved the workflow of the site. The only migration options that were retained were ones where the flaggers/voters would usually be right, which is to the site's own Meta.

Answer (score 12):

The totally generic "this is just generally off topic" close reason is already accounted for. Those of us with the privilege to cast close votes get this handy option for a close reason:

[image: Among the off-topic close reasons is one reason which is simply named: Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong). There's a text entry box prefilled with the words "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about" - and the rest is left for us to fill in.]

... and we get to say basically anything in there, then cast the close vote. What we write in there becomes a comment on the question, and becomes an actual close reason for that question that people can vote for!

That's exactly how [gomad's comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31792/how-does-one-keep-up-a-poker-face#comment63013_31792) came to be:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a board game.

And it's what the question was closed for.

### Other close vote reasons

These are good requests for well-chosen off topic categories, with one modification: I'd expand the history one to generically state that real-world topics are only acceptable here if an RPG expert would provide better/different/more specific asker than, say, a Historian or Geographer. That is basically [our criteria for real-world topics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - see the quote box halfway down.

That said, though: there isn't a huge need for them, and as far as I'm aware, close reasons aren't added lightly - it takes work on behalf of the mods and SE team both to add and adjust them, so it's done when it's super necessary.

Video game questions are our most common class of off topic question, but even those we only get once every month or two. Other kinds of off topic questions are much rarer, and for now - until one of them becomes much more common - we can completely make do with the *Other* field I mentioned.

On that basis, I'm not sure there's a strong need for them to be added - yet! But until then, you can bet people with close vote privileges will swoop in on these questions we don't have a better off topic reason for, and vote to close them with a custom reason. We don't get a huge number of questions here, so every question gets many eyes on it.

Comment: I generally don't see a third option like that when flagging, my third option there is usually (if at all present) “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network”, which then goes on to let me choose “It belongs on meta.rpg.stackexchange.com – discussion, support, and feature requests for this site” as the only option. New question on
http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/off-topic-flagging-options-vary-with-the-questions, thus my question&confusion.

Comment: That's as designed. Nobody sees that option when flagging - it's purely for close voters.